# Using Central Limit Theorem to Prove Claims About Distributions? (Desperate)

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, chi-squared-distribution

I am kind of confused for the following questions:

[image]

I know for the second question that I have to use the delta method but I can't even get past the first question here. Like, my thinking initially was that the CLT takes the form of $\sqrt n(\bar{x} - \mu)$ -> ... and so, I know that here, I am minimizing the difference between the sd observed and the variance expected for this distribution (the normal one), but I know that the distribution of the variance is chi squared, so the $\bar{x}$ if I change it over to that dist is $s^2$ in this question and same with the $\sigma^2$. However, then the expected value there is $n-1$ and since n tends infinity.. this obviously doesn't make sense. Can someone give me a good understanding of questions like these? My final is coming up and need help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

$$s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 - \frac{n}{n-1}\bar X^2$$

Now look at the first term and think whether you can apply CLT to it. Then think what is the limit of the second term in terms of convergence of probability. Recall Slutsky lemma and think how can it help you.

Remember that the CLT in its simplest form is stated as the following. For iid random variables $\xi_i$ with $E\xi_i=\mu$ and $Var(\xi_i)=\sigma^2$ the following holds:

$$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i - \mu\right) \xrightarrow{D} N(0,\sigma^2).$$

Also it is useful to remember that LLN applies for the same random variables:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i \xrightarrow{P} \mu.$$

Another useful fact is the continuous mapping theorem which states that if

$$\eta_n\to \eta,$$

then

$$g(\eta_n)\to g(\eta),$$

where $\eta_n$ is a sequence of random variables and $g$ is a continuous function. The convergence in this case can be both in distribution and in probability. Do not confuse it with delta method though!

Comment: I see that the first term is the sum of squared normal distributions which is the chi squared distribution but I can't think in my head how to apply CLT to it. Instantly, my head goes to, okay we take the expected value of this to be $\mu$ and then i just get confused because there is a sum in front and I am used to just thinking about it as it was a sequence of random variables, not a sum.... I am trying though to think this through

Comment: I see that slutskys theorem could work here if the limiting distribution of the second term is a constant lol, hm...

Comment: Forget the $\chi^2$, it is an exact distribution of the sum. The question asks about the asymptotic distribution. The usefulness of CLT comes from the exact distribution of the sum does not matter.

Comment: Yes the limiting distribution of the second term is constant.

Comment: Okay, sorry I think before I go on any further with solving this question, I have to ask... what does it even mean to "Use CLT to prove..." To me, I see the CLT as the equation you posted above but using it, I get confused. Is it just a matter of finding a mean and variance? and plugging it in? I don't seem to have much intuition about this...

Comment: Look at CLT as a formula where you need to plug things into. Take $\xi_i=X_i^2$ and try to find the missing pieces to plug into the CLT formula. What is $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ for such defined $\xi_i$?

Answer (score 0):

I give you some suggestions to solve (a).

Remember $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta_0)\overset{D}{\rightarrow} N(0,\frac{1}{I(\theta)})$, you will use CLT here.

Here $\hat{\theta}=s^2$ and $\theta_0=\sigma^2$

Next calculate Fisher informtion from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ treat $\sigma^2$ as $\theta_0$, then you will get $\psi$

Comment: Won't I get a Hessian 2x2 matrix for the fisher information here? I assume you mean find the derivative of score function and take negative expectation? Do I just do it with respect to sigma^2 twice? Also, how does the chi square distribution factor in here? Maybe that's a different way to do it but I would still like to know...

Comment: Yes, but seems this is not the intention of the question, mpkitas answer is the intenetion of the question I think

Comment: I am interested in the source of the statement. What is $\hat\theta?$ MLE estimate of the $\theta_0$?

Comment: Yes it is. When n is large it does not matter for the biased mle